# ERROR: function avg(boolean) does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to know how frequently an event happens, and the occurence of this event in my database is recorded by setting a boolean to 'TRUE' and the non-occurence is setting it to 'FALSE'.

But when I am try to select the value by using the function avg() it returns me this error:
ERROR:  function avg(boolean) does not exist

**How can I measure the event frequency and at the some time keep a good performance ?**

Thank you.

Joao

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will coerce the value into 0's and 1's

```
select avg(val::int);
```

Comment: I believe @Chris.Caldwell's response is more useful.

Comment: @botchniaque Just curious, which database are you using, where `AVG` on an int column returns an int? I tried this solution on both Redshift and Snowflake, and in both cases just casting to int was sufficient, avg still returned a float.

Comment: @sid-kap you're right - casting to `int` is enough.

Comment: Actually, I'm using Redshift, and the `avg` of an `int` returns an `int` for me, so definitely need to cast to `::int::float` in my case, not sure why that doesn't seem to be the case for everyone though...

Answer (score 13):

You could do this:

```
AVG(CASE WHEN  myBooleanAttribute = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: AVG(CASE WHEN myBooleanAttribute THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) would also work

Answer (score 9):

If you cast as int you will get an int average, which isnt very useful. Instead try:

```
select avg(val::int::float4);
```